# Why I can not use pst-solides3d

Tags: errors, pstricks, pst-solides3d

I would really love to use package pst-solides3d to draw 3D solids but so far I haven't been able to work on it. I am just a beginner of using pst-solides3d so and I do not know how to figure this following code out. When I was compiling the simple following code, always was being the error, that is: ! Undefined control sequence.
Please anybody helps me with that, many thanks to you.

Code complied:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(1,1)(2,2)
\psSolid[object=cube,a=2,action=draw*]
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se, and thanks for posting a good minimal example document.  You need to compile `pstricks` code with LaTeX+dvips or XeLaTeX, not pdfLaTeX.

Comment: Or you load `auto-pst-pdf`  *after* `pstricks` and  add to the command line the `--enable-write18` switch (MiKTeX) or `-shell-escape` (TeX Live, MacTeX). Then you can use `pdflatex`.

Comment: Thanks Mister for your helpful supplies. Could you please show me where the "command line" is. It is in Texmaker (that  I am using) or in somewhere else ?. Because I do not know where to put "--enable-write18" in.

Comment: \documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(1,1)(2,2)
\psSolid[object=cube,a=2,action=draw*]
\end{pspicture}
\end{document} (my code is still not OK, error stands still)

Answer (score 1):

Hope you may update your package which are based on Pstricks, hence I don't have any error on your code, see the screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much sir. I have tried your suggestion, that is, I have compiled by: Latex+dvips+ps2pdf+View PDF as well as XeLatex + View PDF. But the error:! Undefined control sequence is still on. I do not know why is that on my laptop. You have mentioned that I need to compile pstricks codes, so do I need to do somethong else to get it done ?

Comment: Do I need to add more packages or fix something in my inner system of the machine

Comment: Pl mentioned what type of TeX you are using and what version, I am using MikTeX V2.9